# Can't set env variables in my vuejs2 project

Tags: vuejs2, environment-variables, undefined, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to set my API URL in a .env file, my .env file is in the root folder of my project. I'm using VUE_APP_ prefix.

According to the doc .env file is loaded in any case. So should'nt I be able to get it everytime?

I m using MacOS, no Vuex.

My .env file

```
VUE_APP_API_URL: '"http://localhost:3000/"'
```

My .vue file

```
        data() {
            return {
                test: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
            }
        },
```

I expected to get http://localhost:3000/ but I get undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong in your `.env` file. It's `VUE_APP_API_URL =` with `=` not `:`.
And you don't need double **and** simple quotes.

It should work this way:

```
VUE_APP_API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/'
```

Comment: I must have been tired this week end lol,  thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reference the .env file in Webpack so that the variables get compiled into the build. The reason why you can't reference the variables is that they're not parsed into your build/public folder.

I'd use something like 
https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack